# How do extend text in cell beyond the cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some text in a cell. The Alignment-Orientation is 90 degrees. I want the text to extend beyond the cell.  Wrap text is off. I don't want the row height to increase. What do I need to do?
Image attached, see cell B8.

[image]

Comment: Merge the cells, B4:B8

Comment: I believe the only way to do that is to merge the cells vertically as needed to display the text length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the home tab, under alignment, you'll see "Merge & Center"

Highlight the cells you need (Which looks like B1:B8) & click "merge & center", you can also un-merge this way.

Comment: Just to note: Merge & Center defaults to the content being centered in the merged cells, but you can also apply left or right alignment to position the text as needed.